# GlTexSubImage2D slow and uses 4% of CPU

Tags: c++, opengl

I am using glTexSubImage2D for update window that uses openGL.

I see that this function takes a lot of time to return and it also takes 4% of CPU.

Here is the code that I use:

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, (*i)->getTextureID());
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, (*i)->getWidth(), (*i)->getHeightView(),
    GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,(*i)->getBuffer());
```

Does anybody know of a better implementation?  Something with better performance that will take less CPU?

Right now this is making my program sluggish.

Comment: You are at the mercy of the driver on that you could look into using a pixel buffer http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_pbo.html

Comment: I encountered the same high CPU usage when `glTexSubImage2D` is used. However, as I searched around in the internet, I found a similar function, `gluBuild2DMipmaps` and the CPU loading seems to be gone.

Answer (score 6):

There are some things you can do, though how much you can benefit from them depends on the circumstances.

First, make sure that your pixel upload format is correct for the driver's needs. You seem to have that taken care of with `GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`, which is likely the driver's preferred format for `GL_RGBA8` image formats.

However, if you happen to have access to OpenGL 4.3 or a driver that implements [ARB_internalformat_query2](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/internalformat_query2.txt), you can actually detect at runtime what the preferred upload format will be. [Like this](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glGetInternalFormat):

```
GLint pixelFormat, pixelType;
glGetInternalFormativ(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGBA8, GL_TEXTURE_IMAGE_FORMAT, 1, &pixelFormat);
glGetInternalFormativ(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGBA8, GL_TEXTURE_IMAGE_TYPE, 1, &pixelType);
```

Of course, this means that you will need to be able to modify your data generation method to generate data in the above format/type pair.

Once you've taken steps to appease the driver, your next possibilities are using [buffer objects to store your pixel transfer data](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Buffer_Object). This probably won't help overall performance, but it can reduce the CPU burden.

*However*, in order to take the best advantage of this, you need to be able to generate your pixel data "directly" into the buffer object's memory by [mapping it](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object#Mapping). If you are able to do this, then you can probably get back some of the CPU cost of the upload. Otherwise, it may not be worthwhile.

If you do this, you should use proper [buffer object streaming techniques](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming).

Double-buffering your texture may also help. That is, while you're rendering from one texture object, you're uploading to another one. This will prevent GPU stalls that wait for the prior rendering to complete. How much this helps really depends on how you're rendering.

Without knowing more about the specific circumstances of your application, there's not much more that can be said.

Answer (score 3):

If your texture really is changing every frame, then you will want to use a double buffer to transport your data to the GPU.  (If it's not changing every frame, then the obvious optimization is to only upload it once!)

Each frame, you upload data to one buffer and draw data from the other buffer, and you switch which buffer you use each frame.  This will speed everything up because the GPU will not have to wait for the memory transfer to finish.

A tutorial on PBOs is somewhat beyond my ability to condense into an answer, but "[OpenGL Pixel Buffer Objects](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_pbo.html)" is a decent reference, and I would look at the "[OGL Samples](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ogl-samples/)" repository to see how PBOs work.

**However,** If you can't compute a texture frame in advance, then there is no real advantage to using PBOs.  Just use `glTexSubImage2D`.

**That said,** 4% of CPU might *not* be a problem.

Comment: i open few child windows and each 1 takes 4% and it gets to 25% real quick

Comment: @guymininberg: It still doesn't sound like a problem... how do you know that reducing CPU utilization will speed up your application at all?

Comment: if someone will install it on the computer and see this result... the program will be removed quickly :(

Comment: @guymininberg A good program is a program that uses all the available resources. If you're doing something intensive and hitting high CPU utilization, that's good code and bad CPU. If you're doing something lightweight and still hitting 25%, you need to optimize the code or get a new CPU (or both).

Comment: @Vladislav: No, it is not the goal of a program to use all available resources. That is wasteful.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Well, all available resources required for its job, that is.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be changing the data of a texture every frame in order to update your screen. Textures are meant to be loaded once and rarely (if ever) changed. If you are trying to write to individual pixels on your screen, I would recommend not using OpenGL, and use something more suited to the task, like SDL.

Edit: Okay, this isn't necessarily true. See discussion below.

Comment: There are **tons** of legitimate reasons to change a texture every frame, the most obvious one is to play a movie.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Really? For every frame that you're trying to play, you would re-upload the data into a texture on the GPU? Are there not more efficient ways to do that, like... uploading more than one at a time so that you can actually get a decent framerate?

Comment: @Xymostech: That would require both the ability to decompress multiple frames at once (which taxes the CPU) *and* the GPU memory bandwidth to upload that much data to the GPU.

Comment: There are many reasons why thats fine - render to texture post processing etc

Comment: @JustinMeiners: post-processing of the type you describe would require a full-round-trip: read the rendered data, process it on the CPU, write it back to the GPU. That's rather more involved than what he's doing, and a lit more taxing in terms of performance. Though still doable, it would be more efficient to do the post-processing via a shader.

Comment: @Xymostech: I don't think there's an advantage to batch-uploading textures, unless they're small.  Besides, saying that OpenGL is not suited to the task is simply false.  If you have a movie, for example, it takes a significant amount of CPU to decode a single frame, so you want to upload each frame as it's ready.

Comment: @NicolBolas sorry should have been a comma between render to texture and post processing - two seperate concepts that both could use realtime gltexsubimage2d updates

Comment: @JustinMeiners: Why would render-to-texture need updating from the CPU? The whole point of RTT is that it's a pure-GPU process.

Comment: @NicolBolas I see. Your right it would take place on the GPU unless it was some weird scenario where you were reading from a texture modifying on the CPU and reuploading.

Comment: @Xymostech: I think you'll find that any OpenGL implementation that isn't utterly ancient (e.g., pre-2.1) is going to be very good at uploading data to the graphics card.  If you only want pixel-by-pixel access, you can keep the texture in RAM and upload it to the GPU every frame without worries.

Comment: Well, I guess TIL for real about OpenGL textures. I guess I always figured that you shouldn't be uploading data and changing textures so much, but it appears that there isn't a way to upload large amounts of data without.

Comment: i try to load a web page into the window and edit it with openGL...

Comment: @guymininberg: "*i try to load a web page into the window and edit it with openGL*" What does that mean? OpenGL doesn't know anything about HTML. Or are you saying that you took a *picture* of a web page and tried to "edit it"? If you're "editing" it in OpenGL, that means you're rendering to it. So why the frequent uploads?

Comment: what i mean is that i load URL (which change all the time) into my window and i use openGL to make this window "look" better... shadows/tile/mirror and other stuff.

Comment: @guymininberg You need a pure GPU renderer for the webpage. Mixing CPU and GPU rendering is an extremely tight bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13112332/7616532)'s comment thread, you're rendering a website on the CPU side (or the rendered image goes through the CPU), but applying OpenGL shaders to it. If it's so, you need a GPU-side renderer, rendering the webpage **and** applying shaders on the GPU side. This way, you'll no longer upload each frame to the GPU through the CPU, and the CPU will be free from rendering needs, **as it's intended to be**.